# Submit by pressing enter asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am wondering why this, submitting on pressing enter, is only working on ie and not on google chrome...

This is the code I use actually :

```
<div class="TxtBox">
        <asp:Panel ID="lepanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="Connect">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtUserLogin" runat="server" TabIndex="1" Text="login" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
                Display="Static" ControlToValidate="TxtUserLogin"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:TextBox ID="UserPass" runat="server" TabIndex="2" Text="password" TextMode="Password" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
                Display="Static" ControlToValidate="UserPass"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="Connect" runat="server" OnClick="Connect_Click" TabIndex="3">connect</asp:LinkButton>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Label ID="MsgError" runat="server" />
        <div class="ForgottenPass">
            forgotten password ?
        </div>
        <div class="RememberMe">
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkBoxRemember" />
            stay signed in
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Because you use a link button and not a real button.

Comment: Alright ! It worked but there is no way to put css on a BUTTON ?
It's not taking the css of my linkbutton ..

Comment: yes there is a way , what css ? By the way I make this answer

Comment: good it's working ! It's just because it's not A anymore but an INPUT in the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, when you add as default a link button (actually a link) and not a real button then there is a case that is not trigger properly.

So if you change it to real button you make it work.

Answer (score 4):

A `LinkButton` renders as a HTML anchor tag.

HTML anchor tags do not submit HTML forms. Therefore when you click <kbd>Enter</kbd>, this is not actioning any submit button.

---

A `Button` renders as HTML `<input type="submit" />`

An `ImageButton` renders as HTML `<input type="image" />`

These elements will both action your form.

---

Therefore changing `LinkButton` to `Button` or `ImageButton` is the best solution.

Using a `LinkButton` is also bad for users who do not have javascript enabled.